How do humans have intuition about the universe
When physicses see emperic results they build a model that make sense to them and used this model to predict things. Like the particles model we assume everything has quanta and when new force found we assume it a particle because it make sense to us but what the point in doing this the axioms of the universe may be random. For example there it might be some random things that happing just because it the way it works.
Does when something is simple and related to other rules of the universe it have higher chances to be true?
For example how enstain could knos that gravity and acceleration have a relation just from f=ma , And not just think it randomly happened that way was he just lucky?

You may read and study Kant's famous CPR which is dedicated to the structure of human intuition about the universe in relation to intelligibility and sensibility...

Often we don’t, our intuitions get in the way. See Einstein refusing to believe science could progress with nonlocality (most physicists studying quantum mechanics now believe in nonlocality after John Bell and related experiments) or the intuition breaking Galilean relativity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_ship

@JKusin - It is not clear from your comment how nonlocality, or some other physical intuition, "breaks" Galilean relativity. This article https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/88/3/207/148995/Galilei-proposed-the-principle-of-relativity-but states: The danger in calling the classical transformation “Galilean” is that students begin to believe that Galilei's principle of relativity is somehow limited to the classical transformation and classical mechanics, thus neglecting its universality. Do you know a reference describing physical models that do not incorporate Galilean invariance?

@SystemTheory I didn't say nonlocality does--"See Einstein refusing to believe science could progress with nonlocality... or the intuition breaking Galilean relativity". Then to claim Galileo's ship didn't change our intuitions seems egotistical. It did my intuition of the physical world and I've never even thought to find an pre-Galilean source because that revelation seems ubiquitous. I don't even see how your link applies.

@JKusin - The link claims the universality of Galilean invariance, which is my recollection, and you seem to be referencing some other physical theories of nonlocality that "break" the principle of Galilean invariance. It is not clear to me what your short comment means in the context of published physics. That is why I asked for a reference.

@SystemTheory My comment merely brings up two different cases where our intuitions have been in error. A specific example of Einstein being against non-locality, and while we can't poll him today, would likely agree with the majority of quantum physicists, who believe in non-locality due to modern experiments and papers. Non-locality is well documented I don't feel the need for a source. A more general example of intuition break is G's ship, which shows there are reference frames, unaccelerated motion of the cabin can't be ascertained within the cabin alone, etc,

...something again I feel no need to source because of the gravity of his discovery basically. Whether quantum non locality actually breaks G relativity is much more contentious and beyond the scope, and not something my comment hints at in either direction.

@JKusin - Thank you for clarifying the intended meaning.

Intuition is subconscious pattern recognition. If you want an intuition about a kind of thing you haven't experienced much of, you must either go out and experience it, or accurately simulate experiencing it.
The model is a mathematical relationship between mathematical objects. It only exists in the mind, or in symbolic form on something you've written down, so there's no need to go out anywhere to experience it, and simulating it and really experiencing it are the same (unless you make math mistakes).
To get intuitions about the how the model relates mathematical objects, we practice relating mathematical objects with the model.
If it is a good model that reliably predicts reality over the relevant domain, and we have practiced naming the mathematical objects after parts of reality, we can use intuitions about the model to have intuitions about parts of reality of which which we can have no direct experience, like quanta.
By and large the model doesn't make sense to anybody without this deliberate effort to practice it until intuition can work. What the model does is comport with measurement.

Alright, first and foremost. Not everything is a model... This is surely a scientologist approach. In fact, Ron L. Hubbard was a fan of using models to simply defend his horrid beliefs. Because it was deemed a belief, he never felt threatened, at the least via his ego. Second, a simulation is not an accurate experience of that which is reality. Sure, they exist within reality, however, always depend upon a foundational blueprint which then may be copied and altered for variations. These are nothing but faux expressions of reality, within reality. Pure fantasy, even in simulation theory.

So are we doing those experience without having snese of what the results gonna be .or we have some Idea why it an instressting thin to check

@Daniel I think that what you're really looking for is Feynman's Character of Physical Law lecture series, which can be accessed free and legally online as both video and transcript, and is likely available in book form at any urban library.
